# PyCharm "Can't update: no tracked branch" for VCS Update Project

Tags: git, version-control, pycharm

In PyCharm 2016.2, I'm trying to VCS=>Update Project, but I'm getting this error.

"No tracked branch configured for branch master in Git repository /Users/troyscribner/git To make your branch track a remote branch call, for example, git branch --set-upstream master origin/master"

In the terminal, I tried: "git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master", but the error does not go away.

If I select the project in the project explorer, and I select Git=>Repository=>Pull, the project updates correctly from git, so I am able to update the project that way.

How do I get rid of the Update Project error?

Answer (score 2):

To trouble shooting the issue, you can follow below steps:

1. **Check if the local git repo has remote(s)**

   In the terminal wondows, you can use the command `git remote -v` to check if the local repo has remote(s). And make sure there has remote name `origin`.
2. **Check if remote repo has master branch**

   List the remote repo branches by executing `git branch -r` in terminal window. If the output not contains `origin/master`, you should push the local `master` branch into remote repo by `git push -u origin master` (when the current branch is `matser`).

Then  update the master branch in Pycharm should be successful.

And for the reason why update not work but pull works is mainly caused changes are pulled from a different branch (or remote) into local `master` branch.